# AjaxFileUpload reloads page on upload ONLY for image files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been working to debug an intermittent issue I've been experiencing with AJAXFileUpload. I'm moving our code away from another uploader and have worked this into several pages already. I have realized that the uploader is reloading the page after completing the UploadComplete code in the code-behind ONLY for images. I can upload .pdf, .docx with absolutely no problem but as soon as I try .png, .jpeg, .gif, etc the page reloads immediately after the upload.

I can't find anything that would suggest the behavior between these two types of files should be different and I'm assuming I'm missing something.

Here is my upload control:

```
<ajax:AjaxFileUpload AutoStartUpload="true" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="() => $('#btnSaveThumbnails').toggle()" ClientIDMode="Static" style="max-width:800px;display:none" runat="server" ID="thumbUploader" />
```

And here is the code-behind for the UploadComplete function:

```
If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(tempFilePath) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFilePath)
        End If

        sender.SaveAs(tempFilePath & e.FileName)

        Session("docUploaderFiles") = If(Session("docUploaderFiles"), New List(Of String))
        CType(Session("docUploaderFiles"), List(Of String)).Add(e.FileName)
```

Like I mentioned, these work exactly as expected for non-image file types in my experience.

UPDATE: I have narrowed it down to being caused by the .SaveAs call in the code-behind. Removing just that line causes no page reload.

UPDATE: I have found this issue is specific to my machine. The uploader works on other local environments as well as on our production application. Possibly something to do with my IIS.

Comment: You use a button click/toggle when "all is done" event with your btnSaveThumbs and that I suspect causes a final post-back when ALL files are done. so it looks like your final "all" event does a post-back (and that is often needed). So from what I can see so far, the upload each file event not causing a post-back, but the final upload "all" done event is (and as I noted, this is a common setup). So, I would check the all done event code - as that looks like the source of the post-back. So each file event fires and then final "all event" does fire for final event and post-back should not matter

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal It is actually causing a full page load and not a postback, as verified by some breakpoints in my debugging. The big mystery for me is that this behavior DOES NOT EXIST for .doc, .pdf, .xlsx (and I'm sure other extensions), but only for image files (.png, .jpeg, .gif tested).

Comment: put png, jpeg etc. in the allowable file types. A page/script error perhaps? Agree this don't make sense. Do you display a thumb nail , or something else about that file after the upload? Or just the file is up-loaded? I use that control a lot - even modified it to allow passing of values for each event (so I don't have to use session).  So, do you have specials code in the final "all" event?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried the allowable file types with no success previously and again just now for good measure. Not seeing anything in my JS console. I am not doing anything else with the image on the page. There are no front-end or back-end "all" events. I am also using this same implementation on multiple pages that all have the same experience.

Comment: I would whip up a test page and drop in the file up-loader. Hard code the save as file name if you must - but try a test page and see if this occurs. Remember, if any of the 3 server side events have a error - then that could also be the issue. So, I would build a quick test page - see if that works.  I'll try a test page myself, as I only ever up-loaded pdf and zip files. But I can't imagine why a png/jpeg would be a issue? Perhaps you have a custom http handler for jpeg files on that site - but even then that should not matter.

Comment: I am very gracious for your help. I will try an independent test page. A note is that we have been using CuteWebUI Ajax Uploader for quite some time, uploading all files without issue. To be sure, I have verified there are no bizarre http handlers for my image files.

Comment: try my suggestion in the answer I just posted - see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why this would not work.

However, I have OFTEN found that if you don't specify and wire up the CLIENT side events, then the up-loader can barf on you.

So, try this for your test:

```
        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            OnClientUploadComplete="MyComplete" 
            OnClientUploadCompleteAll="MyCompleteAll" 
            OnClientUploadStart="MyStart" AllowedFileTypes="txt,zip,png,jpeg"
            OnClientUploadError="MyError" ChunkSize="16384" />

        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <script>

        function MyStart() {

        }

        function MyComplete() {

        }

        function MyCompleteAll() {

        }

        function MyError(e) {
        }


    </script>
```

Note how I added the client side events. I have found in some cases that without the client side events, then problems arise, so I drop in the 4 blank client side events.

EVEN if you not using the client side events, try putting them in as per above. So, I dropped in 4 client side events - without any code in those stubs.

My server side code for this test is this:

```
Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadCompleteAll

    Debug.Print("all done")

End Sub

Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadStart(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadStartEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadStart

    Debug.Print("start upload")

End Sub

Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadComplete

    Debug.Print("file done")

    Debug.Print(e.FileName)

End Sub

Protected Sub AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedFileError(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)

    Debug.Print(e.StatusMessage)


End Sub
```

I would also check + clear out non ASCII chars in the file name. I seen funny files - and they blow out a error.

So, I do this:

```
    Dim strCleanFile As String = TrimNonAscii(e.FileName)
```

and

```
Public Function TrimNonAscii(ByVal value As String) As String

    Dim pattern As String = "[^ -~]+"
    Dim reg_exp As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
    Return reg_exp.Replace(value, "")

End Function
```

So I trim out spaces, and also rip out other funny values. (from a Mac or other devices, they actually allow non legal windows chars in the file name, but windows does not.

Comment: Using the exact code you've supplied, I did not have a page reload. This led me to try my original uploaders without the server side code, which worked as well. This leads me to believe the server side code is causing the issue, but it is all pretty straight-forward and I can't imagine why images would act differently than other filetypes.

Comment: If server side code blows a error, then things fall appart. Perhaps the test file is open/locked/not relased. Try a differnt png file. I have server side code wire up for above, and will post my server side code.

Comment: I have deduced that it is the sender.SaveAs() call that is causing the page to reload. It is not throwing any errors, though. And another note is that the SaveAs() call IS actually saving the image.

Comment: Try the 4 server side code stubs. And make sure the 4 client side stubs exist. If all events fire, then you have some server side error occurring - either path name, or some locked file. Dump the file save code in the test page - ensure that all events fire. As noted, it been some time, but I seem to recall that if all 4 client event js stubs don't' exist, then problems occur - so I put them in, even when not needed nor used. Also check the t

Comment: Don't use sender. Use         AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs()

Comment: Done, no change in behavior.

Comment: Ok, then see my last code addition. I would blow out spaces in the file, and a few other characters as per that last code snip posted.

Comment: I have made this change with no success. The files seem to be saving properly. I'm not catching any errors and they do end up where I'm trying to put them, and completely in tact.

Comment: Then I think the jQuery button toggle is the offender. I would specify a separate routine, and not put that jquery expression as the final up-load all event client side. jQuery has to go and "modify" the page - and I suspect that final toggle button code is the issue. Remove it, for testing - and eventually move that out to a standard js code stub, not that expression.  I mean if the test page save as causes the post-back, then we really are missing somthing here.